# Close Google Map directions in ionic

Tags: ios, google-maps, ionic-framework

I want to show directions from my current location to an address in my app.

I can successfully open the directions by using:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr={{location.lat}},{{location.lng}}">Get directions</a>
```

But once open I cannot return to my app. Is there a way to close the map again?

*note I appreciate this will only work correctly on iOS, I will handle android separately.

Comment: Have you considered implementing it through angluar with [ui-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps) ? `vm.locationClicked = function (marker) { window.location = 'geo:' + marker.latitude + ',' + marker.longitude'; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to do it with `comgooglemaps-x-callback`:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#specify_a_callback_url

this example opens Google Maps on iOS with a call back to chrome:

> comgooglemapsurl://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=Tokyo+Tower,+Tokyo,+Japan&sll=35.6586,139.7454&sspn=0.2,0.1&nav=1&x-source=Chrome&x-success=googlechrome://?resume=true